# Anything wrong if I've used jquery mobile for normal websites?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Anything wrong if I've used jquery mobile for normal websites? I meant, about functionalities, or will that override any of features for normal jquery.

I read somewhere jquery mobile is based on jQuery, I am wondering how it will affect when using both at a time.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? As far as I know, jquery mobile is targeted specifically for mobile devices and alike, for normal websites, you can use jquery ui, if you need rich controls....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is a Javascript framework, jQuery Mobile (confusingly) is an UI framework that uses jQuery. It is meant for developing Mobile UI but surely you can develop any site with it!

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse functionally this would work, BUT its not a good idea to use JQuery mobile for normal websites. JQuery Mobile is designed for mobile devices with limited screen space and designed for touch. Resulting website would look ugly in a desktop browser.

You need to understand what is JQuery mobile:

- JQuery mobile (JQM) is a framework for creating mobile web applications. Mobile screens are limited in screen size, and JQM takes care of the layout and stuff.
- JQM is built on top of JQuery. JQuery is a javascript framework for manipulating DOM and it takes care of the differences in underlying browser. It provides elegant ways to manipulate DOM.